# Is "$p + p'q = p + q$" a law in Boolean Algebra?

Tags: boolean-algebra, boolean

Is "$p + p'q = p + q$" a law in Boolean Algebra?

$$p.(q+r)=(p.q)+(p.r)\\p+(q.r)=(p+q).(p+r)\\p+\overline{p}\ q=p+q$$

My book says that it is one of the distributive laws, but I don't see it anywhere on the internet or any other books. Is it actually a distributive law or is my book incorrect?

Comment: Have you made a truth table to see if it works?  I wouldn't call it a distributive law, but that is just nomenclature.

Comment: Please don't use pictures, use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @RossMillikan It does work but I don't find anywhere except in my book that it's called distributive law.

Comment: If you couldn't find all the valid Boolean laws (corresponding to syntax trees of low max depth 2 on both sides) online, i.e. $f(x, g(y, z)) = h(x, y)$ etc. for all connectives, then I hereby challenge you to write a program to brute force them all and put them online.

Comment: Hint: the sides of the equation have respective negations $p'(p+q'),\,p'q'$.

Comment: The second one you quote $p+(q\cdot r)=(p+q)\cdot (p+r)$ is a more general distributive law, then set $r=p’$.

Comment: You can always check this out by means of sets: $P\cup(P^c\cap Q)=P\cup Q$ is evidently true.

Answer (score 2):

We can **use** the distributive law to prove it.
$$
p+q = p+1q = p+(p+p')q = p+pq+p'q = p(1+q)+p'q=p1+p'q=p+p'q
$$

Answer (score 2):

We can **use** the distributive law to prove it.

$$p+p'q = (p+p')(p+q) = 1(p+q) = p+q$$

Comment: I was not asking for the proof. I was asking whether or not it is a standard Boolean Algebra law, and if it is, then what its name is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a law, but you're right, very few sources list it ... which is too bad, since it's such a handy dandy rule!

Because it is such an uncommonly listed rule, I doubt you will find a high degree of consensus as far as names go even if you do see it listed, but I've seen it referred to as **Reduction** (of course, don't ask me to remember where I saw that :P ... and a quick Google search hasn't been very successful either  :( ). But I really like the name Reduction (it's certainly how I call it myself): the $P$ term *reduces* the $P'Q$ term to just $Q$.

So while in $P + PQ$ the $P$ term *absorbs* the $PQ$, in $P + P'Q$, the $P$ term *reduces* term $P'Q$

Also, if you haven't ran into this one:

$PQ + PQ' = P$

That one is a bit more commonly listed again, and is fairly consistently known as **Adjacency** (because in a K-Map, the two terms that are being merged represent adjacent groups of cells that can be merged into a single grater block of cells represented by the simpler term) ... this is another super handy dandy rule ... but also often not listed.

Answer (score 1):

$$p+q=p(q+q')+q(p+p')=pq+p'q+pq'=p+p'q=q+pq'$$

because $pq+pq=pq$ and $p+p'=1$.